# Download a file in Safari with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari

Currently, when my user clicks a download button, I make a request to the server to for the file to fetch the file. Once this is done, I want to download this file onto the user's machine.

How do I do this in Vue.js? Or is this a vanilla javascript operation that also works no matter what framework I use?

The files that are downloaded are zip files, and vary in size (somtimes quite large). Should I store them in session/local storage?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download

Comment: it says the webserver is down...

Comment: Refresh, was working a sec ago